# Is it good practice to pass component instance as props to another component in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oop, vue-component

Assume that we are going to make a text edior.

When typing, Component C(Text input section) needs the state of Component B(Font stlye picker) to determine what style to use.

[image]

We can share that state by Vuex, but in OOP, related logic or variables are better to be put in same class, and when other components need the state of that object, just to refer it directly.

If I want to refer components directly, one way is to save some components when they are mounted, and pass them as props to other components as the following.

```
// in <template>
<FontStylePickerVue ref="stylePicker" />
<TextInputSectionVue 
ref="textInputSection" 
v-bind="{
  tylePickerComp: stylePickerComp
}" />


//in Main Component <script>
mounted(){
  this.tylePickerComp = this.$refs.stylePicker;
}
data(){
  return { tylePickerComp : null }
}
```

In Vue, although there are many ways to communicate between components, I never seen any of them passes component instance as props directly like this.
(it works, and very convinient though.)

I know doing like this, in a way, it make system more complicated because components refer each others in a complex relation, but ***I'm just wondering if there is any design pattern like this in Vue, or doing like this has some cons like low perfermance ,etc.***

In the end, in order to clarify the idea, I want to compare what if I pass component as props directly or use common methods in this example:

1. Pass component as props directly:
   Need to save component reference on mounted, but type declartion is once and for all(ex. use InstanceType). Need to deal with null(it's null before mounted).
2. Event bus:
   Emit an event with a promise resolve function as callback to make other components to resovle with their state. This is good because it will keep data or logic in the same class(compare to use Vuex), but you need to write your method in a promise style in order to read resolved result.
3. Vuex:
   Split some variables into global scope, and this is not so compatible for cases which are better to gather logic and data at same place.

Just want to get some idea for this topic, sorry for long article.

Comment: This is mostly an antipattern. By providing the whole instance/state/etc object you're giving a child more control than it needs and results in tight coupling between components that aren't directly related.

Comment: take a look at slots https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Yes, it results in coupling. It's always great to keep everything decoupling, but in some cases, for example, if I need to read many variables in another component, it will take a lot to register events and declare types. Just want to learn more about pros and cons, so thank you for your comment!

Comment: @HKK There's not much to discuss without a specific example what are these "many variables" and how data is handled. But when you pass something and access it somewhere because it's easier to handle it at the destination, over a long period of time you'll end up untangling the clot of data that is manipulated in obscure way. Some parts of the project will take more time to examine and modify, things will become unexpectedly broken and will be harder to fix. These are common cons of bad design decisions.

Comment: @EstusFlask I agree. Eventhough I am considering passing components directly in some cases, there would be additional principles to comply by, which I didn't mention here, in order to keep things from tangling. I would say I will take passing component into account if developing personally with principles in mind, but It's easily to get into mess for others to maintain. Maybe there would be a better balance between "simply read(not allowed to change) state but coupling" vs "longer and scattered code to keep decoupling", which I do not know now.